# Autoscroll to tableviewcell on touch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was wondering if it is possible to autoscroll a tableview on touch?  Basically if you have several cells and you're scrolling through them, and you have half of each cell on the screen and you touch one of them, I want it to scroll so that the one you touch gets centered on the screen. The reason for this is so that if you have buttons and they touch a button  while mid-scroll between cells, it would bring the cell with the button to the center of the screen so they could see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your using something like `myArray.count` to define the amount of cells in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method. So, if you wanna scroll to the cell of the middle position, you can use `myArray.count/2` to find that the number of the row.

```
 NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:myArray.count/2 inSection:0];
[self.myTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Swift version:

```
var ip: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: myArray.count / 2, inSection: 0)
self.myTable.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(ip, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Any chance you can convert that to swift?

Comment: See my edit, I used this page to that:  [link](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/)

Answer (score 1):

Maria's answer converted to Swift:

```
var ip = NSIndexPath(forRow: myArray.count/2, inSection: 0)
self.myTable.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(ip, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
```